# PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied') when importing pandas from Python script on Webhosting Service

Tags: python, pandas, apache, import, permissions

I am running the following script from a Webhosting service (Apache), where pandas and all it's dependencies are in the same folder. Importing Numpy works fine, importing pandas however throws an exception. I tried it with different version of pandas too (0.24.0, 0.24.2 etc.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import traceback

print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print('\r\n')
print('Hello, World!')
print (sys.version)
print('\r\n')

sys.path.append(".")

try:
    import pandas as pd
    print(pd.__version__)
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

Browser Output:

```
Hello, World! 3.5.2 (default, Oct 8 2019, 13:06:37) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] (, PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'), )
```

The reason I am using python on a server is that I already have a python script that depends on pandas and would like to reuse it in a php/web project without the need to rent a whole server. Any clue on how to fix it or how to gather more information on why it fails would be appreciated

Comment: You're only printing the final exception message.  Take out the try/except handling so that we see the entire stack trace.

Comment: As John Gordon mentioned having the full stack trace would be helpful. Additionally, it's considered bad form to use the catch-all except, as it catches all exceptions that might happen. In general, only catch the exceptions that you expect your code can raise.

Comment: I am sorry, but when i take out the try/except the program obviously just crashes and i get no stacktrace since it is running on a Webhosting Service. I don't have any access to it besides ftp. I know this is more than suboptimal, but it is all i have right now, as i don't want to rent a server with full file system access for this project.